# What is the TypeScript compiler argument that allow to specify output js codepage?

Tags: typescript

By default TS RC1 output JS files in UTF-8 but we need him to output JS in ANSI. Is there a compiler argument to do this ?

Comment: Why would you need to do that? If you don't have localized strings in the source files, it would be ANSI characters.

Comment: Well, this application use only one langage (french with accents) for now. Indeed we could localize the resources in a linked js but it would have been nice to have all the code outputed in a single .js file to avoid http request for each script. But if we have no choice that's what we will end up doing.

Comment: But, why is UTF-8 output a problem? That should be the right file format I'd suspect, even with accented French.

Comment: UTF-8 shouldn't be a problem. I'm saving our french translations in a UTF-8 file and it's been working fine.

Comment: If I had started this project, I would have chose UTF-8.

Comment: UTF-8 works fine with french. But we start to use TS on an existing project and all files and the DB are in ANSI. That's why.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no such argument in the tsc compiler (version 0.9.5).

You would have to use other tools to convert UTF-8 to ANSI in generated JS files.

Answer (score 0):

Please note that VisualStudio has **Pre-build events**. I'm not sure that it will help but you can write some **.bat file** to transform UTF-8 chars into codes before compiling.

Comment: If you use Intellij IDEA or WebStorm, you can use File Watcher plugin for this task.

Comment: In our case that would be Post-build events we would use but it's actually a great idea. Thanks